# Swagger ignores xml parameter tag

Tags: asp.net, xml, rest, odata, swagger

i am using Swagger + xml comment file for my Asp.net webapi documentation.

The value in the summary tag is displayed, but the param tag gets ignored.

I have an OdataController v4

```
    // GET: api/L_controller('L')

    /// <summary>
    /// This is my summary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">This is my Description</param>   

    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<L_model> GetL_controller([FromODataUri] string key)
    {           
        return someResult;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's nothing wrong with your code but it's a bug in Swashbuckle.Odata: https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData/issues/73

> "Key param handler overwrites xml-doc commented documentation"

I've observed the same problem. Whenever I use a key (the entity field annotated with [key]) the description is just

key:Code

(Code is the name of the key field in my entity)

The documantation of other, non-key parameters works fine.
One workaround could be to add a remarks tag to your documentation which you use to add a note about the parameter, e.g:

```
/// <summary>
/// retrive user by key
/// {URL}/User(key)
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>this documentaion will be displayed</remarks>
/// <param name="key">this documentation will be ignored</param>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works fine for the problem i posted

I had to customize the swagger document more so i implemented a IDocumentFilter